# Twitter Bootstrap Caurosel.js and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

### How to realize TwitterBootstrap.Carousel.js *"active item"* tag in Rails to work everything right?

This recipe:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

How to mix it with following one:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <% item.item_images.each do |item_image| %>
        <%= link_to(image_tag(item_image.image.url), item_image.image.url) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the class of active only to the first item in your list, otherwise they'll all show.  I got around this by utilizing `each_with_index`.

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <% item.item_images.each_with_index do |item_image, index| %>
        <div class="<% if index == 0 %>active<% end %>">
           <%= link_to(image_tag(item_image.image.url), item_image.image.url, ) %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Of course, this can be refactored quite a bit.